# Value Error: Dimension Mismatch - Python Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification

I'm running a classification model on text data. I used countvectorizer to create the features for the model. After training it, I've tried predicting new instances; however, I keep getting a dimension mismatch error. I know this is because the new instances do not have all the features that the training data has. Still I'm quite unsure how to solve this issue. Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

x = data['text']
y = data['class']

# Transform data
cv_transformer = CountVectorizer()
Encoder = LabelEncoder()

x = cv_transformer.fit_transform(x)
y = Encoder.fit_transform(y)

# Split data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.4, 
                                                    random_state=1) 


Naive = MultinomialNB()
Naive.fit(x_train,y_train)
# predict the labels on validation dataset
predictions_NB = Naive.predict(x_test)
# Use accuracy_score function to get the accuracy
print("Naive Bayes Accuracy Score -> ",accuracy_score(predictions_NB, y_test)*100)

# Testing a new instance

sample = ['my name is john doe']
sample = cv_transformer.transform(sample)

Naive.predict(sample)
```

This last line is causing the error to pop up. Any idea on how to adjust the dimensions?

The error message is the following:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in **mul**(self, other)

```
if other.shape[0] != self.shape[1]:
raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')

result = self._mul_multivector(np.asarray(other))
```

ValueError: dimension mismatch

Comment: what is your exact error message? Add error text as it is you got.

Comment: With error add the dimension of x and y as well.